# Scala Spark/Databricks: .cache() not preventing re-calculation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

This involves some complexity, and I may be unclear on some basics. Here goes:

As I understand it, spark has "transformations" and "actions". Transformations lazily build up a description of what you want to do, and actions make it happen. This can improve performance (allowing optimized plans), or it can lead to duplicated effort if you use multiple actions on a single dataframe, causing the transform to fire repeatedly. To avoid this, .cache() tells Spark to actually "save its work", so the dataframe you call it on shouldn't continue to be re-computed.

My problem is that it doesn't seem to be doing that. I have a function "Foo" that does a lot of computation to produce a (very small) dataframe. Foo runs quickly, and I can display the result. I have another function "Bar" that does a bunch of actions on a dataframe. Bar runs quickly on the (large) original input, but very slowly on the output of foo, even cached and coalesced. I can also "force" the cache-ing by writing the output of foo to disk and then re-reading it, at which point bar runs quickly:

```
display(bar(bigDF)) //Fast!

val profile = foo(bigDF).coalesce(1).cache()
display(profile) //Also fast! (and profile only has 2 rows, ~80 columns)

display(bar(profile)) //Slow!

profile
  .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .save("filename.csv")
val dumb = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("filename.csv")
display(bar(dumb)) //Fast again
```

To me, this says that the .cache() isn't working the way I think it does - the slow call is repeatedly re-calling the transformations in foo, unless I write it to disk and force it to "forget" its history. Can someone explain what I'm missing?

Comment: try repartitioning your dataframe....  your dataframe could be have a small number of partitions or the partitions are highly skewed

Answer (score 0):

`cache` is doing what you expect, seems that there is something strange happening.

I expect that the `coalesce(1)` is the problem, try to leave that away and test if it's running faster. It could be that it destroys parallelism for `bar`.

If nothing helps, try to use `checkpoint` instead of `cache` it could be that the query plan is very long and complex, `checkpoint` would truncate that (it writes to disk)

For further analysis you would need to go into SparkUI to analyze the jobs

Comment: I tried removing the `coalesce(1)` call and replacing `cache()` with `checkpoint()` - I'm not familiar with checkpoint, so it's possible I'm using it wrong. Neither made a difference. I'm not sure what to look for in the SparkUI? (I did note that bar shows ~50 jobs after completion, many of whose DAGs showed the coalesce step before I removed it)